# Ajax beforesend method is not working in some cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, csrf-protection

I have a tile-standard jsp which is included in all pages of my application. I am trying to inject some security token in all Ajax requests of the app and for that purpose I wrote the below snippet into the head element of this JSP. The problem is, in most of the cases, the ajax call gets intercepted as expected and token is injected in the data. But in some cases, beforesend method is not getting called and hence token is not present in the request. I am not sure why some Ajax calls are not getting intercepted while others are. 
Below is the code snippet :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                      var controlId = "<c:out value='${XXXControlIDXXX}' />";

                    // Injecting CSRF token id into data
                       if(controlId!=null) {  
                        var csrfData = {
                            XXXControlIDXXX : controlId                                     
                        }
                        settings.data += "&" + $.param(csrfData);
                       }
                }
            });             
        });
```

Comment: It's very unlikely that the `beforeSend` is failing intermittently. It's more likely that some data is missing in the request, or that you're making the AJAX call before `$.ajaxSetup` is executed.

Comment: @RaviRanjan while the title is the same, the question and solution don't appear relevant to this situation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - How can we make ajax call before $.ajaxsetup?

Comment: If you call any AJAX method before you call `$.ajaxSetup`...

Comment: But my ajaxsetup is in domready, so it should not be possible. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Yes, if the `$.ajax` call is in another domready that's defined before the one that holds the `$.ajaxSetup`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @RoryMcCrossan. For that purpose only, I am using this jsp which is included at the top of all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Big thanks to Rory McCrossan for his inputs which lead me to the right direction. So, the ajax call was happening before ajaxsetup and hence i was not able to set the token. I used the below snippet which does not rely on any document events and just sits on the page and gets triggered on all ajax calls.

```
         $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
           var controlId = "<c:out value='${ControlID}' />";
           if(controlId) {   
             var csrfData = {
                        ControlID : controlId                                       
                    }
             options.data + = "&" + $.param(csrfData);
             }
          });
```